# How to echo a bootstrap modal when user successfully logged in

Tags: javascript, php

I am currently using:

`echo '<script> alert("You Are Now Signed In!"); </script>';`

When a user successfully logs in it shows the Alert but I want to show a Bootstrap Modal.

How can I show the Alert?

Comment: you mean twitter bootstrap modal?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to place a modal in HTML like this:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
     You are signed in now!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and then `echo` the following (note the double quotes)

```
"<script>
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
</script>";
```

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';'`

Comment: @SumonKhan Did you put a semicolon after echo?

Comment: @SumonKhan and also, just to be sure, are you including bootstrap css and js?

Comment: yes, I did. And I changed `' to "` but the modal isn't showing. Should I put the Modal HTML code within the same PHP Block or I can use it outside of the Same PHP Block too?

Comment: you need to put it in the page the script tag will be executed i.e. your HTML

Comment: I did everything like this:

`<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
     You are signed in now!
    </div>
  </div>

    <?php
        if($logvalue == "Loged"){
 echo '<script> $('#myModal').modal('show'); </script>';
    ?>
</div>`

Comment: Okay..Please add your HTML, PHP and JS code in your question.

Comment: Are you writing php and html in same file? Also, check $logvalue! Is it "Loged"?

Comment: Yes, I am writing PHP, HTML, and JS in the same file